# Should rest property of object binding pattern be the last

Tags: javascript, babeljs

As I may see from [feature specification](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Spec.md#rest-properties), **rest property** in object binding pattern should be at the end. So this is not a valid code:

```
var {a, ... rest, b} = obj;
```

But Babel transpiles it without any problem. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good call, looks like a Babel issue to me. I've filed it so we don't lose track of it: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7265